# Parse server error 208 "this auth is already used"

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, parse-server

I inherited an iOS app which is talking to a parse server and using Facebook auth exclusively. We are getting this error from parse server:

> Error Domain=Parse Code=208 "this auth is already used" UserInfo={code=208, temporary=0, error=this auth is already used, NSLocalizedDescription=this auth is already used}

I did some googling and it mentions that this can happen if anonymous user is turned on, but this app did not enable this feature.

What I'm looking for is a hint on how to solve the problem or a hint as to what i can do so that when i detect this user i can fix it for the user.

**UPDATE**

I got into the database and surely enough their are multiple PFUser which have the same Facebook ID. So i guess the solution is to delete one of the two account. I'm still unsure how the data got in this state though.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This means that one user (i.e.: objectId=a) is trying to attach a Facebook userId (i.e.: 1) that is already attached with another user object (i.e. objectId=b)

How can that happen?

Consider that flow:

- user logs in with facebook -> objectId=b, facebookId=1
- user logs out
- user signup with email -> objectId=a
- user tries to link with FacebookId=1
- **this auth is already used**

To circumvent that problem you should ask the user to login instead of linking.

Comment: Thx for the answer, the issue is that we don't allow user to login via email. Only Facebook... Any other way this could happen?

Comment: Did you enable anonymous users in your client app?

Comment: No anonymous user is not enabled and i don't think it ever was. My theory is that the iPhone app was trying to link the account twice when sign in completed within 30 ms and thus the server created the 2 PFUser. Though i have not been able to verify that

Comment: That seems to be a reasonable assumption: see: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/1488